# laravel blade @include with localised variable

Tags: laravel, include, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I have this code:

```
 @include('admin.members.members_form', ['submitButtonText' => '__('member.edit')'])
```

and in the admin.members.members_form:

```
{!! Form::submit($submitButtonText, ['class' => '"btn btn-primary"']) !!}
```

THe inclusion is not working (with this version I have an error with single quote, I tryied with \'member.edit\' have no error but  whe button with text `__('member.edit')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like that (without quote)

```
 @include('admin.members.members_form', ['submitButtonText' => __('member.edit')])
```

Comment: Working perfect, Thanks